# How could I make the title of a TreeView Column editable?

Tags: python, treeview, gtk, pygobject

I based on [editable cell example](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cellrenderers.html), I was able to figure out how to make cells of a column in a table (implemented by TreeView) editable.

But, how could I make the title of the column editable?

Comment: How do you wish to edit it? Editing the column title in place is difficult, in Gtk3 almost impossible. Now if you would open a dialog and grab the text out of a entry, you can update the column title with GtkTreeViewColumn.set_title('new title name').

Comment: In place editing is not the goal here. The provided example for making cells of the table editable does not have it in place either, when a cell on the table is double-clicked, above the cell a text entry pops up. The same method I wish to have, for the titles of the columns.

Comment: Could I see the current code you have? This will give me a starting point.

Comment: I have realized that in my project the column title editing is not really a requirement, rather I want the user to choose the title from a fixed number of options. After this realization, my solution was presenting another TreeTable with the options and the user drag-and-drop one option from the option table and sets the title of the column where the options was dropped. Dear Nerd thanks for trying to help.